# VBA - Range formula not working - if(or(isnumber(search) not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to use this formula in vba, can you please help me with this:

```
Range("L2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CTA",K3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dissolved",K3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ZBA",K3))),"Yes","No")"
```

When I am doing it manually its working fine but when I am trying it thru VBA I am getting error, please correct me.

I tried to look into old question but not able to match with this

Answer (score 2):

That's not a valid string, the interior `"` must be escaped as `""`

```
Range("L2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CTA"",K3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Dissolved"",K3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ZBA"",K3))),""Yes"",""No"")"
```

Comment: i am not aware why we should be using double quotes twice and whats the benefits of using it but i tried this too its not working still. thanks for your time....

Comment: If you don't escape " the line of code you pasted would not compile.  If the above is not working you need to edit your question (with the corrected  string) and tell us the error your encountering.

Comment: Just tested that code and it works as advertised. Personally I'd simplify the formula a little: `Range("L2").Formula = "=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({""CTA"",""Dissolved"",""ZBA""},K3)),""Yes"",""No"")"`

Comment: This one work sir :) First one i am getting error saying Expected : List separator or ).. Thanks expert :) if time permits please correct me on te old one...